# Is there a difference between .ui-widget :active and .ui-widget:active?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, google-chrome, css

I am experiencing a very odd bug with Chrome 17.0.963.56. Following is a screenshot:

[image]

When the page first renders, the Salutation combobox looks fine. However as soon as you check the checkbox above, the weird image appears. Clicking anywhere on the page then causes it to go away. Unchecking the box causes it to appear again. I tried to repro in jsfiddle, but could not.

I found 2 different ways to make this bug go away. The first has to do with the HTML and CSS structure of the combobox:

```
<div class="field ui-helper-clearfix @Html.IdFor(m => m.Salutation)-field">
    <span class="label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Salutation)
    </span>
    <div class="input">
        <div class="combobox">
            <div class="text-box input">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Salutation)
            </div>
            <a class="text-box down-arrow">
                <img class="text-box down-arrow" alt="" 
                    src="/content/icons/transparent.png">
            </a>
            <div class="autocomplete-menu">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="messages">
            <div class="top callout border">
                <div class="top callout bg">
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="validation">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Salutation)
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.combobox .text-box.input {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 20px;
    border-right-color: transparent; /* was border-right-width: 0; */
    border-right-width: 0;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
```

Basically, the border comes from a div wrapper around the input element. The input itself has no border. For normal text box wrappers, the border radius is 5px. However for the combobox, I override that CSS value to give the top & bottom right corners a radius of zero. This is to make it blend into the drop-arrow element for the combobox.

When I completely remove the right border on the textbox wrapper (using border-right-width: 0;), the anomaly appears. When I instead keep the right border and give it a transparent background color, the anomaly goes away.

**However I also discovered that removing /content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css made the problem go away.** Trial and error led me to the following line in jquery.ui.theme.css:

```
.ui-widget :active { outline: none; }
```

When I remove this line, or change it to `.ui-widget:active { outline: none; }` (note the absence of the space between widget and :active) the problem also goes away -- even with the text box wrapper having a right border width of zero.

This issue does not occur in Firefox, IE, or Safari 5.1.1 (7534.51.22), only in the Chrome version mentioned above. So it seems it could be a Chrome bug.

I have never seen a state selector used with a space like that before. Most of the time, things like :hover, :link, :active, etc, come immediately after the selector. Does the jQuery UI selector above mean "apply outline:none; to all :active elements nested beneath a .ui-widget element"? Or does it mean "apply outline:none; to all :active .ui-widget elements"? If there is no difference by removing the space between .ui-widget and :active, I would prefer that solution over making the text box wrapper right border transparent instead of giving it a width of zero.

Another odd thing is that the Suffix combobox is not affected -- yet it uses the same exact CSS and HTML structure as the Salutation combobox. Weird...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a difference between .ui-widget :active and .ui-widget:active?

There is. `.ui-widget :active` means "an active successor of an element with the class "ui-widget". `.ui-widget:active` means "an active element with the class "ui-widget".

Provided that other browsers render this case correctly, I suggest reporting a bug against Chrome (preferably, give a reduced test case): http://new.crbug.com

Comment: Thanks Alexander, that's good to know. Still, a very odd behavior with Chrome. I just now realized the colors in the background image correspond to the border colors for the text box wrapper -- dark gray on top and left, lighter gray on bottom and right.

Comment: Hmm, you have a border-radius with one border invisible, that might be an issue - have you tried setting your border-right to something visible?

Comment: Yes, one of the solutions I found was to keep the right border width and give it a transparent background-color. That is probably the solution I will go with for now, given your answer. However the inability to repro in other browsers makes me think this is a Chrome bug, and not inappropriate use of CSS3.

Comment: In this case, the best option is to report a bug against Chrome (preferably, give a reduced test case): http://new.crbug.com

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely do that. Please copy this last comment into your answer and I will mark.